# 16x16 sudoku solver using hex characters

Tags: c++, sudoku

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

#define N 16

using namespace std; 

string grid[N][N];
string allowed[16]= {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
int reoccur = 0;

void getFromFile()
{
    char character;
    fstream fp; 
    fp.open("optionalnew.txt",ios::in);
    for(int x  = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < N; y++)
        {
            fp >> character;

            grid[x][y] = character;
            cout << character;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

bool allowedCol(int col, string num)
{
    //Check if a number is already present in a col
    for(int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        if(grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false; 
}

bool allowedRow(int row, string num)
{
    //Check if a number is already present in a row
    for(int col = 0; col < N; col++)
        if(grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false; 
}

bool allowedBox(int boxRow, int boxCol, string num)
{
    //Check if a number is already present in a box
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            if(grid[row+boxRow][col+boxCol] == num)
                return true;
    return false; 
}


bool isEmpty(int &row, int &col)
{
    for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
            if(grid[row][col] == "X")
                return true; 
    return false; 
}

bool checkValid(int row, int col, string num)
{
    return !allowedBox(row - row%4, col - col%4, num) && !allowedCol(col, num) && !allowedRow(row, num);
}



void dispBoard()
{
  cout << " --------------------------------------------" << endl;
  for(int row = 0; row < N; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < N; col++){
      if(col == 4 || col == 8 || col == 12 || col == 0)
        cout << " | ";
      if(grid[row][col]=="X")
        cout << "_ ";
      else
        cout << grid[row][col] <<" ";
      if(col == 15)
        cout << "| ";
    }
    if(row == 3 || row == 7 || row == 11){
      cout << endl;
      for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        cout << "-----------";
      }
      cout << endl;
  }
  cout << " --------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

bool solveSudoku()
{
    dispBoard();
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    reoccur+=1;
    //cout << reoccur << endl;
    int row, col; 
    if(!isEmpty(row,col))
        return true;
    for(int num = 0; num < 16; num++){
        if(checkValid(row, col, allowed[num]))
        {
            grid[row][col] = allowed[num];
            if(solveSudoku())
                return true;
            grid[row][col] = "X";
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Here Is The Sudoku Problem:" << endl; 
    getFromFile();
    dispBoard();

    // Solving Problem
    if(solveSudoku()){
        cout << "Solved" << endl;
        dispBoard();
    }
    else{

        cout << "No Sol"; 
    }
}
```

When running nothing happens, I assumed it wasn't working at first but calling the dispBoard function at the start of the solve function, I find that values are being added to the grid, however never reaching a conclusion. Is this because I haven't given the computer enough time to reach an answer? If so, what sort of changes can I potentially make to optimise my code.

Comment: Could you please post your `"optionalnew.txt"`?

Comment: 0XXXXXBA3X68X5XX
XXBX9XDXFX0X4XXX
XXXXXXFXXXXADX13
XX3X7XXXXXCXXXEX
DXX3XF8XXCX2XEXX
C21XXXXB8XD5XXXX
9XX86XXCXXAFXX74
X0XX1XAXX4XXXX8D
XXX6XXXXXEXXX397
FEXXXX97XXXC5X6A
XX9AXXXXBXXX8XDC
8XXXDXCXXAXXXXFB
XXXXXX5XXXXXXXCX
XXX7CAXDX6EXXX3X
1CX0EXXXD7XXA9XF
EX4XX7XFXX5XX0XX

@VladFeinstein

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Comment: learn to use a debugger, it would be easy to break in and see if its doing what you intend

Comment: @HrudaySasankYadavalli please see my `UPDATE 3` below for encouraging news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using a "brute-force" approach, trying every possible combination. Did you do an estimate of the number of such combinations?

Are you familiar with [this](https://www.transum.org/Software/MathsMenu/Starter.asp?ID_Starter=100) story?

<s>You have 16 options for the first cell you try, times 16 for the next one, and so on. On empty board you'd have 16^256 combinations. I don't know the name for such a value, but I doubt that your computer will last long enough to check them all.</s>

OK, you might have 100 or 120 cells filled. So it'll "only" be a 16^130 :)

Do you play Sudoku? Do you use any strategy beside brute-force?

Oh, and for optimization - use `char` instead of `std::string` to store a single character.

Additional reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

**UPDATE:**

After I've converted your code to use `char`, to my surprise, that puzzle was solved during my lunch break. Didn't time it, but it was under 30 min. Release build.

```
 --------------------------------------------
 | 0 _ _ _  | _ _ B A  | 3 _ 6 8  | _ 5 _ _ |
 | _ _ B _  | 9 _ D _  | F _ 0 _  | 4 _ _ _ |
 | _ _ _ _  | _ _ F _  | _ _ _ A  | D _ 1 3 |
 | _ _ 3 _  | 7 _ _ _  | _ _ C _  | _ _ E _ |
--------------------------------------------
 | D _ _ 3  | _ F 8 _  | _ C _ 2  | _ E _ _ |
 | C 2 1 _  | _ _ _ B  | 8 _ D 5  | _ _ _ _ |
 | 9 _ _ 8  | 6 _ _ C  | _ _ A F  | _ _ 7 4 |
 | _ 0 _ _  | 1 _ A _  | _ 4 _ _  | _ _ 8 D |
--------------------------------------------
 | _ _ _ 6  | _ _ _ _  | _ E _ _  | _ 3 9 7 |
 | F E _ _  | _ _ 9 7  | _ _ _ C  | 5 _ 6 A |
 | _ _ 9 A  | _ _ _ _  | B _ _ _  | 8 _ D C |
 | 8 _ _ _  | D _ C _  | _ A _ _  | _ _ F B |
--------------------------------------------
 | _ _ _ _  | _ _ 5 _  | _ _ _ _  | _ _ C _ |
 | _ _ _ 7  | C A _ D  | _ 6 E _  | _ _ 3 _ |
 | 1 C _ 0  | E _ _ _  | D 7 _ _  | A 9 _ F |
 | E _ 4 _  | _ 7 _ F  | _ _ 5 _  | _ 0 _ _ |
 --------------------------------------------
Solved
 --------------------------------------------
 | 0 F 7 E  | 4 1 B A  | 3 D 6 8  | C 5 2 9 |
 | 5 6 B 1  | 9 C D 3  | F 2 0 E  | 4 7 A 8 |
 | 4 8 2 C  | 5 0 F E  | 7 B 9 A  | D 6 1 3 |
 | A D 3 9  | 7 8 6 2  | 4 5 C 1  | B F E 0 |
--------------------------------------------
 | D B A 3  | 0 F 8 4  | 6 C 7 2  | 9 E 5 1 |
 | C 2 1 4  | 3 E 7 B  | 8 9 D 5  | F A 0 6 |
 | 9 5 E 8  | 6 D 2 C  | 1 0 A F  | 3 B 7 4 |
 | 7 0 6 F  | 1 9 A 5  | E 4 B 3  | 2 C 8 D |
--------------------------------------------
 | 2 1 C 6  | A B 4 8  | 5 E F D  | 0 3 9 7 |
 | F E D B  | 2 3 9 7  | 0 8 4 C  | 5 1 6 A |
 | 3 7 9 A  | F 5 E 0  | B 1 2 6  | 8 4 D C |
 | 8 4 0 5  | D 6 C 1  | 9 A 3 7  | E 2 F B |
--------------------------------------------
 | 6 3 8 2  | B 4 5 9  | A F 1 0  | 7 D C E |
 | B 9 F 7  | C A 0 D  | 2 6 E 4  | 1 8 3 5 |
 | 1 C 5 0  | E 2 3 6  | D 7 8 B  | A 9 4 F |
 | E A 4 D  | 8 7 1 F  | C 3 5 9  | 6 0 B 2 |
 --------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Timed it, got 2,477 seconds (~41 min).

**UPDATE 3:**

Implemented what Sudoku calls `notes` - keep a set of all possible values for each empty cell. Only go through those in your `solveSudoku()` function. That cut time in half.

Implemented simple strategy: go through the board row-by-row, see if my notes in that row have a unique number; then assign it to the cell it was found in. Solved in 262 seconds.

Repeat that for column-by-column. Solved in **1.9** second.

I can do the same block-by-block, but am loosing interest. Unless someone will challenge me to a competition :)

I am not posting any code here, assuming that OP wants to do it.

**UPDATE 4:**

Added one more step: iterate through each cell to see if their notes have a single number; then insert it. Solved in **161 ms**!

**CODE:**

You'd need to include

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
```

Then change your definition to

```
char allowed[16] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };
```

and also define

```
unordered_set<char> notes[N][N] = {};
```

Here is the function that builds "notes", I call it right after loading data from the file:

```
void buildNotes()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                for (int num = 0; num < 16; num++) {
                    if (checkValid(row, col, allowed[num]))
                    {
                        notes[row][col].insert(allowed[num]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `for` loop in `solveSudoku()` becomes:

```
for (char num: notes[row][col]) {
    if (checkValid(row, col, num))
    {
        grid[row][col] = num;
        if (solveSudoku())
            return true;
        grid[row][col] = 'X';
    }
}
```

I've implemented my strategy like this (in the `main()`):

```
getFromFile();
dispBoard();

buildNotes();
while (unique()) {
    while(singles())
        ;
}
```

And here are the "smarts":

```
bool unique()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        map<char, int> found;
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                for (char num : notes[row][col]) {
                    found[num]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (auto i : found) {
            if (i.second == 1) { // found unique number in this column
                for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
                    if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                        if (notes[row][col].find(i.first) != notes[row][col].end()) {
                            grid[row][col] = i.first;
                            // remove it from each cell in that col
                            for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) {
                                if (grid[r][col] == 'X')
                                    notes[r][col].erase(i.first);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        map<char, int> found;
        for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                for (char num : notes[row][col]) {
                    found[num]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (auto i : found) {
            if (i.second == 1) { // found unique number in this row
                for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
                    if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                        if (notes[row][col].find(i.first) != notes[row][col].end()) {
                            grid[row][col] = i.first;
                            // remove it from each cell in that row
                            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
                                if (grid[row][c] == 'X')
                                    notes[row][c].erase(i.first);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool singles()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                if (notes[row][col].size() == 1) {
                    char num = *notes[row][col].begin();
                    grid[row][col] = num;
                    // remove it from each cell in that col
                    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) {
                        if (grid[r][col] == 'X')
                            notes[r][col].erase(num);
                    }
                    // remove it from each cell in that row
                    for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
                        if (grid[row][c] == 'X')
                            notes[row][c].erase(num);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that the Wiki page you linked also says "a brute force algorithm *can be* a practical method to solve Sudoku puzzles.". I guess that limiting to only the *valid* solutions cuts down the search space quite a bit.

Comment: @Bob__ yeah, I realized it now...

Comment: @VladFeinstein Thanks so much for the help! Would it be possible for you to share your solution? I'm slightly lost with the whole notes thing, is it by any chance similar to what I have as my allowed array? Thanks

Comment: @HrudaySasankYadavalli sure, shared above ^^. BUT - you will miss all the fun! :)